# How to pass the prefix argument using a list in the `interactive` clause of a command definition?

Tags: commands, interactive, prefix-argument

How can I use prefix argument with list in the interactive clause?  It is the more general way instead of Code Characters.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't clear.  But I'm guessing you're asking how to pass the value of the prefix arg as an argument to a command, in an `interactive` spec that gets a *list* (not a *string*) argument.

As the doc tells you:

- Use `list` to put things in a list.
- Use variable `current-prefix-arg` to get the **raw** prefix-arg value.
- Use `(prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)` to get the **numeric** prefix-arg value.

Example:

```lisp
(defun cmd (raw numeric)
  (interactive (list current-prefix-arg
                     (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)))
  (message "RAW: %S, NUMERIC: %S" raw numeric))
```

That's equivalent to this:

```lisp
(defun cmd (raw numeric)
  (interactive "P\np")
  (message "RAW: %S, NUMERIC: %S" raw numeric))
```